# How to make JPanels respond to MouseDragged?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

So, I've been working on a program that lets you click/drag over a grid of JPanels, and changes the background colors of the JPanels that you have clicked on or dragged over (you can set the colors using JRadioButtons). I've gotten the point where if I click on a JPanel, it responds and changes colors. However, if I simply do:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    ((JPanel)e.getSource()).setBackground(color_chosen);
}


public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("Calling mouseClicked"); // debugging
    mouseClicked(e);
}
```

the program only responds to mouse clicks, and doesn't recolor the backgrounds of the JPanels affected by the mouse drag. In addition, its puzzling to me that "Calling mouseClicked" still prints out, but no background colors change.

I'd appreciate some help trying to figure out where I went wrong, so that any panel that I drag over changes its background color to a pre-specified chosen color.

Thanks.

Comment: Going to need to see a runnable example that demonstrates the problem...